# iOS8 custom keyboard - add UIImageView

Tags: ios, ios-keyboard-extension

I built a keyboard with the keyboard extension available in iOS 8. I created a custom view and I want to create a button image background, but the image does not appear in the keyboard. What needs to be done to put an image on my custom keyboard?

My code (call to the view):

```
UIView *layout = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"kyyBoardLogic" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[self.inputView addSubview:layout];
```

Thanks: Yakir.

Comment: What is actually happening when you do this? Are you sure that `loadNibNamed` is actually finding a file? If so, do you know what is at index 0 of the array it returns?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a subview, use this code. This adds the view as an input view to the given superview.

```
self.keyboard = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"keyView" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
self.inputView = (id)self.keyboard;
```